# "javax.servlet.ServletException: unkown device" in MGWT when generating Html5Manifest File

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, gwt-platform, mgwt

I use mgwt and GWTP. On [this page](https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/HTML5Manifest) there is written how to generate a Html5Manifest file.

When running my app in dev mode I get the following error:

```
[WARN] /testmobile.manifest
javax.servlet.ServletException: unkown device
    at com.googlecode.mgwt.linker.server.Html5ManifestServletBase.doGet(Html5ManifestServletBase.java:115)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
[ERROR] 500 - GET /testmobile.manifest (192.168.178.21) 3009 bytes
```

This is my gwt.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN"
  "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='testmobile'>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.core.Core'/>
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.inject.Inject' />
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.resources.Resources' />

    <inherits name="com.googlecode.mgwt.MGWT"/>

    <!-- Other module inherits                                      -->
    <inherits name='com.gwtplatform.dispatch.Dispatch'/>
    <inherits name='com.gwtplatform.mvp.Mvp' />

    <inherits name="com.googlecode.mgwt.linker.Linker" />
    <add-linker name="permutationmaplinker" />

    <extend-configuration-property name="html5manifestlinker_files" value="./" />
    <extend-configuration-property name="html5manifestlinker_files" value="index.html" />
    <extend-configuration-property name="html5manifestlinker_files" value="index.css" />


  <!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
  <entry-point class='test.mobile.client.Testgwtp'/>


    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED" />  



    <set-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.modules"
                                value="test.mobile.client.gin.ClientModule"/>

<set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
    <source path='client'/>
    <source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

This is my web.xml file:

```
<!-- Default page to serve -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/wiki/HTML5Manifest -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ManifestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.googlecode.mgwt.linker.server.MGWTHtml5ManifestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ManifestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testmobile.manifest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is my index.html file:

```
<html manifest="/testmobile.manifest">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="testmobile/testmobile.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

**How can I prevent this error?**

Edit: I found here https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/issues/detail?id=294 that you have to change the permutation when you change the default permutations but I do not know how?

**Edit:** After inserting

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
```

to my web.xml file I have a compilation-mappings.txt file with this content:

```
3CF5F28779DC3102DF51566915301A19.cache.js
locale default
mobile.user.agent mobilesafari

4086115B0405F7965FF008436AFD8C97.cache.js
locale de
mobile.user.agent mobilesafari

69E3CCD13FF82D3DA3EBC7EDAE5A1588.cache.js
locale de
mobile.user.agent not_mobile

C35440AF74DD89E43810D85756CC4CEE.cache.js
locale default
mobile.user.agent not_mobile

Devmode:devmode.js
```

Comment: do you have a compilation-mappings.txt file in your gwt output js folder?, if so could you post its contents?

Comment: @ManoloCarrascoMoñino no I do not have such a file. Could you post it if I need it?

Comment: I recomend to use the xsiframe linker, with that linker you get this file, them we can figure out which permutations and which properties are in your project

Comment: @ManoloCarrascoMoñino what do you mean by "xsiframe linker" how do I use it?

Comment: Add this line to your `<add-linker name="xsiframe"/>` to you `.gwt.xml` this would be the default linker someday. When you compile with that linker you will get a `compilation-mappings.txt` in your js folder with the info of your permutations.

Comment: @ManoloCarrascoMoñino I updated my question with the results and the compilation-mappings.txt file. Still not working same error. What to do?

Comment: @ManoloCarrascoMoñino any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you add  `<inherits name="com.googlecode.mgwt.MGWT" />` to your gwt.xml file, it should work.

Some properties (namely *mgwt.os* and *mobile.user.agent*, I guess) may be absent. They are useful to decide which manifest has to be served.

Comment: I have this dependency in my web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "/" before your modulename in your html-file

`<html manifest="/testmobile.manifest">`

it should look like

`<html manifest="testmobile.manifest">`

Comment: This does not fix the problem. Any other idea?

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same error, do you know how to solve it ?